# What Items do creepers destroy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What items can you retrieve intact if a creeper explodes in certain biomes? I usually get sand and grass. Can you also get sandstone and stone as well?

Comment: Please fix your title to be more descriptive.  This is an ongoing issue with your questions.

Comment: Creeper blast do not "reward" you. They *destroy* your world, but you are lucky to get 25% of blocks not destroyed, but dropped as items. Also, any items already dropped are destroyed outright, as an added "bonus".

Comment: is this a better question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get any mineable block except for obsidian. Just blow up a creeper next to it. These blocks are not rewards, they are the blocks the creeper has destroyed. 75% of the blocks are destroyed outright and 25% will leave behind the block as if it had been mined.

A while ago there was a [thread on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/19e0kj/i_forbade_pickaxes_charcoal_buckets_saplings_and/) with a server for which this was the primary means of getting resources since most tools were banned. You may be interested:

[image]

> Cobblestone is a sign of wealth, as we can only obtain it through creepers/TNT explosions!

Comment: So you can get wood and coal as well and its all retrievable?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's a terrible way to mine though as 75% of the items are destroyed.

Comment: It should be noted that new FTB Unleashed back has a mod called creeper collateral that makes it so creepers destroy 0% (changeable) of the blocks they blow up.

Comment: In Pocket Edition, creepers don't blow up sand (yet).

Comment: Does coal drop as "burnable" coal or as coal ore blocks (like treated with silk touch pick)?

Comment: @SF It drops as an item, not a block. Explosive damage is like mining blocks *without* silk touch.